# How to check programmatically if an application is installed or not in Android through asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have designed a website which is responsive and it opens in Android and iOS.

I also have a supported app for the same which has a feature for sharing links. When the link is clicked it will redirect the user to the website.

Is there a way to find out if the app has been installed on the device (Android/iOS) which the website is running on through MVC?

Please help me with a few suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No. A webserver has no idea whether or not an app is installed on a phone.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to know. Do you need to understand if link has been clicked on your app from Android or iOS?! Do you want to know if user has your app installed? Easier way is to do like Facebook (did) and LinkedIn does...always redirect your user to the shop to install your app (and keep a cookie to do not do it each single time...)

Comment: Thanks @mituw16 ,@Adriano Repetti for the suggestion.

Comment: @mituw16 What i wanted to know was whether is it possible for the user to know if the app is installed on the device through Website MVC code.

Comment: @BoscoFernandes No... like I said, a webserver (aka MVC code....) has no idea what apps  are installed on a phone.